# Ultracold atoms and General theory of Relativty

Tags: general-relativity, specific-reference, condensed-matter

I am looking for good reviews for the subject of Ultracold atoms and it's application in test of General theory of relativity. I am planning to pick up this topic as a semester project, can somebody guide me ?

I am basically looking forward to some good books and papers which gives me a flavor of theoretical aspects of this subject.

I came across an website which says about Quantum gauge theories and Ultracold atoms and that has interested me a lot. 
http://cordis.europa.eu/search/index.cfm?fuseaction=proj.document&PJ_RCN=10276613

Answer (score 2):

The only connection between ultracold atoms and GR that I know of is [this suggestion](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4098) for doing interferometry with ultracold atoms. This seems pretty speculative though.

Comment: Jason Hogan (still in Kasevich's group) is still working on this topic and making progress with the experiments.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting experiment to construct a Black Hole in ultracold atom systems. The idea is to artificially create a velocity speed field greater than the superfluid speed, which indicates somehow a particle cannot escape the boundary.

Ref: 
Phys. Rev. Lett. 85, 4643
arXiv:0803.0669